# PHP/mysql Add value to current value - Diff than others asked

Tags: php, sql-update

I have tried every one of the other ways people have posted to add a new value to the current, and they have all failed.

Ex: `` UPDATE `some_table` SET `value` = `value` + 1000 WHERE `id` = 1 ``
Returns in Db: `23+1000` ... or `0` ... If I do: `UPDATE some_table SET value = value (+ 1000) WHERE`id`= 1` .. as Suggested by some others.

Here is my actual code for comparison:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$cash = $_REQUEST['cash'];
$score = $_REQUEST['score'];

$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name', cash='$cash',      score='$score'        
WHERE name='$name'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0) {

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name  (name, cash, score) VALUES      ('$name','$cash','$score')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

}
```

....

Now the question is: How do I add the new incoming $cash & $score to the existing Ones.. Ex in the DB: cash|23 score|91  New incoming is cash|22 score|18 and have it UPDATE as cash|45 score|109 .. Keeping in mind each new incoming will be different...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: mysql doesn't use `+` for concatentation. it would be impossible to get `23+1000` in your field, especially if that field is a numeric type. And note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 0):

store the current value in a variable 
$old;
then 
add desired value to $old
$new = $old + 10;
then do an sql update

Comment: As for Mark B. it is possible because it is happening if I use that format, and how could you know i am vulnerable to any thing, all you are seeing is very small portion of the code.

Comment: store the current value in a variable $old; then add desired value to $old $new = $old + 10; then do an sql update

Comment: above will not work because I DO NOT want a preset number input..
People please read ALL of a person post before answering, it would save every one a lot of time.